# Teradata locks table for read while accessing to table through view with access rights

Tags: sql, teradata

This is really weird.

I have  2 view, one with access rights and other with read rights to table.

```
replace view v1_read as locking row for read
select id1 from t1;

replace view v2_access as locking row for access
select id2 from t2;
```

Then I  run such select query and look explain plan:

```
select id1, id2
from v2_access left join v1_read on v2_access.id2=v1_read.id1;
```

Teradata blocks table t2 for read, but it should block for access. Is it bug?

I can say Teradata to start it block for access manually this way:

```
lock table t2 for access -- before the query
```

However there is the problem with such solution - administrators does not give such grants.

- TD Release: 15.10.03.07
- TD Version: 15.10.03.09

How  can I fix that?

Comment: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: @dnoeth update question info

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if this is documented behaviour, I would never create a view with `lock row read` (it's the default anyway). You better talk to your DBA to contact Teradata support.

Comment: @dnoeth They say, that if you write such select query with join without specifying anything , TD will get max rights from both view. So this is why `t2` blocked for read. This is at least strange. One more point, I found the query, that seems to be used same joins, but locks work as excepted

Comment: Finally administrators gave grants to manually block table for access))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write such select query with join without specifying anything, TD will get max rights from both view. So this is why `t2` blocked for read.

1. Always check blocks with `explain`
2. If you arent agree, manually block it `lock table t2 for access`